# Google Analytics data is not showing reporting but Tag Assistant says it's working

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I noticed that my new client's Google Analytics has suddenly stopped working. The only recent changes I have made to the Analytics was adding custom reports but I don't think that should have messed anything up. [Analytics Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anLTr.png)

I have added Google Tag Assistant and the debug extension and both seem to be showing that the code is working fine.

Around the 13th of December - when the sessions first drop - is when a hosting error did occur. A very long story short the transition from the previous company to me did not go very smoothly and there was an ICANN ownership error, probably among other things. I can provide more details if necessary. The Wordpress site was moved from websitesettings.com to GoDaddy.

I checked the filters that were set up before and they seem fine. In the property settings under Admin, it says that there have been property hits in the last day, 7 days, and 30 days but in the info tracking section it says no data has been received in the last 48 hours. When I send a test hit to the page my real-time data remains at zero.

[These are screenshots of everything compiled together because I can only list two links for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tdGY.png)

Any help would be appreciated as I am quiet stumped. Please let me know if I need to expand on any points. Thank you~!

[edit] I have also re-added the code into the theme's header.php file via copy+paste and as a plugin (insert headers and footers). Both ways technically worked according to the Google Tag Assist.

Comment: Check the settings for the "hostname" filter (again). Since this is an include filter it will throw away everything that does not match, so that is the most likely culprit. Also create an unfiltered view, as a backup, and to check if GA works at all.

Comment: I think that worked! :O

Comment: (It's not letting me edit my first comment) Thank you! That is very weird because I never added that filter and I don't know if it was there before. Is it possible that the filter was there and somehow changed its effect or do you think someone added it without me knowing?

Comment: Google Analytics does usually not add filters all by itself :-) If you go to the admin section of your GA account there is a "history" menu item in the account settings section (left of the three columns) that should allow you to find out when and by whom the filter was added.